# How to get the Java webservice request in C#

Tags: c#, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to see SOAP data my client application sends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439430/how-to-see-soap-data-my-client-application-sends)

I'm consuming a Java webservice from a C# windows form application, but the webservice is throwing an error, so I need to check the request XML to validate the data that I'm sending to the Web Service.

In C#, is there any way to get or see this XML request?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) tool for this.  Fiddler allows you to monitor request/response that you are sending from your machine.